# Route not taking the element HomePage from functional component / JSX element type does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

Im having issues where the route wont take the element as is. Trying to use typescript for this project, and I'm running into this issue with vague results online, as I am also trying to use functional components mostly if possible.

The error in question: `JSX element type 'HomePage' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

I've already tried fixes like casting the page as a React.ElementType, but nothing is working so far and I'm just left puzzled.

Let me know if anything else is needed.

**HomePage.tsx**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, ReactNode, ReactElement, FunctionComponent} from 'react';
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';

import Holder from 'holderjs';

export interface IHomePageProps {}

const HomePageComponent: FunctionComponent<IHomePageProps> = (props) => {
  const [carouselSlide, setCarouselSlide] = useState<number>(0);

  const handleSelect = (selectedIndex: number, e: any) => {
    setCarouselSlide(selectedIndex);
  }

  // component (un)mounting
  useEffect(() => {
    Holder.run();
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <main className='container bg-dark text-white vh-min-100 h-auto flex flex-wrap'>
        // content
      </main>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const HomePage = HomePageComponent as React.ElementType;

export default HomePage
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, ReactNode} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes as Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import 'bootstrap';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import './App.scss';

import SiteNavbar from './components/Navbar';

import HomePage from './pages';

function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <SiteNavbar/>
      </header>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I'm unable to repro the error/issue you describe. Here's your code copy/pasted into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/route-not-taking-the-element-homepage-from-functional-component-jsx-element-ty-71w23d).

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I'm thinking theres something wrong with the dependencies. I could try to reproduce with the following deps from the sandbox, but I think i'll see if creating a new project might help too..